# A function that calls X function

Tags: python

I want to basically turn a list element into a function with
the do function. This way any pre-written funcction i can call by just use a 
do(list[x]).

What im trying to do is a function that takes away the quotes of a list element and then executes the function that is in that list element.

---

```
def func():
    print "python"

def func1():
    print "is"

def func2():
    print "awesome"

def do(fun):
    fun()
#I think the problem is here


funs = ['func()','func1()','func2()']

print ''.join(funs[0])
do(''.join(funs[0]))
```

---

Edit:

> What im trying to do is a function that takes away the quotes of a
>   list element and then executes the function that is in that list
>   element

Comment: Why are you putting strings into the list instead of the functions? And what's the point of `do(funs[x])` rather than just `funs[x]()`?

Comment: because i want to turn them into a function later. If i leave them as functions the will all run (i dont want this) and then turn into a None.

Comment: They won't run if you do e.g. `funs = [func, ...]` (put *the function* in the list) rather than `funs = [func(), ...]` (put the *result of calling the function* in the list).

Comment: Cool!, but what happens if they have arguments how would you do that?

Comment: Do the arguments need to be stored too? If so, look into `lambda` or `functools.partial`. If not, just pass them whenever you call the function as you would if you were using its name (`funs[x](foo, bar)`).

Answer (score 5):

You don't need the extra functions, and you don't need to turn them into a string either:

```
def func():
    print "python"

def func1():
     print "is"

def func2():
     print "awesome"

funcs = [func, func1, func2]

for function in funcs:
    function()
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, it basically works like this. Note that the list contains the functions themselves, not a string.

```
def func():
   print "python"

def func1():
    print "is"

def func2():
    print "awesome"

def do(fun):
    fun()

funcs = [func, func1, func2]

for function in funcs:
    do(function)
```

Output:

```
python
is
awesome
```

**EDIT:**  If you do want the list to contain the functions' names as strings, use `eval()`:

```
funcs = ['func', 'func1', 'func2']

for function in funcs:
    do(eval(function))
```

Comment: No need for a custom `do` method, just use python's `apply`

Comment: No need for a separate function at all. `function()` is what you should be doing.

Comment: You know ; my answer to this was your EDIT (*but without using ``eval()``*) :/ I would **never** advocate the use of ``eval()`` ever!

Comment: `eval()` is really strange here. Even finding method through `getattribute` would be better.

Comment: @JamesMills: There are occasional good uses of `eval`. 99% of the time, especially for novices, what looks like a good use for `eval` is actually a good use for higher-order programming (like this case) or using a real data format and parser or … But where it really is the right thing, it's certainly better to use `eval` than some clumsy workaround that would have the same security holes/debugging issues/performance problems as `eval` anyway…

Comment: @abarnert I agree; I'd just rather not see answers upvoted or accepted as the "right answer" that encourage potentially poor practices :)

Comment: What would you do if func had parameters?

Comment: @CarlTheodoroPosthumaSolis: You would just redefine `def do(func, *args, **kwargs): return func(*args, **kwargs)`. (Unless you mean you want the parameters to be bound in at the time you create `funcs`, in which case you'd use `partial`.)

Answer (score 2):

If you *really* want to execute arbitrarily named functions from a list of names in the *current* global/module scope then this will do:

**NB:** This does NOT use the potentially unsafe and dangerous `eval()`:

**Example:**

```
def func():
    return "python"


def func1():
    return "is"


def func2():
    return "awesome"


def do(func_name, *args, **kwargs):
    f = globals().get(func_name, lambda : None)
    if callable(f):
        return f(*args, **kwargs)


funs = ["func", "func1", "func2"]

print "".join(funs[0])
print "".join(map(do, funs))
```

**Output:**

```
$ python foo.py
func
pythonisawesome
```

You can also individually call "named" functions:

```
>>> do(funs[0])
python
```

Note the implementation of `do()`. This could also be applied more generically on objects and other modules too swapping out `globals()` lookups.

Comment: Is the `*args` good for something? I mean, you're calling it without arguments.

Comment: Can you do it individually? e.g just print python?

Comment: @CarlTheodoroPosthumaSolis: Yes; ``do(funs[0])``

Answer (score 0):

As the people above have said the best way is to define a dictionary of functions, as functions are objects in python this is possible

```
def One():
   pass
def Two():
   pass
functions = {"ONE":One, "TWO":Two}
```

You can then call it like this:

```
functions[input]()
```

If you want to give true control to the user (And I DO NOT recommend doing this) you could use the eval function.

```
eval(input+"()")
```